# Why does a derived class from CRTP template not initialise the static variables?

Tags: templates, c++17, factory, derived-class, crtp

So I'm trying to create a factory based on CRTP. For simplicity, I will just include whatever is relevant here. I got two questions which might be irrelevant to each other, but was stuck trying to find the keywords.

```cpp
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

static auto& GetFactoryMap() {
    static vector<string> GLOBAL_FACTORY_MAP;
    return GLOBAL_FACTORY_MAP;
}

template <typename Derived>
struct Registrar {
    static int DoRegister() {
        auto name = typeid(Derived).name();
        GetFactoryMap().emplace_back(name);
        return 1;
    };
    inline static const int _hello = DoRegister();
};

struct Foo : public Registrar<Foo> {};

int main() {
    cout << GetFactoryMap().size();
}
```

Compiled with `x86-64 clang-8.0.0`, flag `-std=c++17`.

**QUESTION 1:** The program returned `0`: https://godbolt.org/z/5c74TePT5. I expected it to print `1` as defining the class `Foo` should also define a `Registrar<Foo>`, which in turn will initialise the `_hello` and call `DoRegister()`.

But when I do this:

```cpp
int main() {
    cout << Foo::_hello << endl;
    cout << GetFactoryMap().size();
}
```

Then it did print `1` (the `_hello`) and `1` (the map size).

**QUESTION 2:** so I found out how to solve the first issue by dummy-calling `_hello` inside `Registrar` constructor.

```cpp
template <typename Derived>
struct Registrar {
    Registrar() {
        (void)_hello;
    }
    ...
}
```

But thing is, I still don't know WHY it can fix the issue. And even after I did that, the `DoRegister` seemed to only get called if I have an empty constructor OR a default constructor OUTSIDE the class definition, as seen by the global map size is only 2: https://godbolt.org/z/Me53q1x86.

What is happening here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. [Implicit instantiation](https://eel.is/c++draft/temp#inst-4)

   > Unless a member of a templated class is a declared specialization, the specialization of the member is implicitly instantiated when the specialization is referenced in a context that requires the member definition to exist or if the existence of the definition of the member affects the semantics of the program; in particular, the initialization (and any associated side effects) of a static data member does not occur unless the static data member is itself used in a way that requires the definition of the static data member to exist.

   TL;DR If it's not used, it's not instantiated.
2. [Explicitly-defaulted functions](https://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.fct.def#default-5)

   > A non-user-provided defaulted function (i.e., implicitly declared or explicitly defaulted in the class) that is not defined as deleted is implicitly defined when it is odr-used ([basic.def.odr]) or needed for constant evaluation ([expr.const]).

   TL;DR `=default` *in the class* only declares a thing; if it's not used it's not defined.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. For my 2nd question, how come adding `Hi()=default` inside class definition has different outcome than adding the `Hi::Hi() = default` outside? You can refer to my godbolt link https://godbolt.org/z/Me53q1x86

Comment: It is right there in the quote. *explicitly defaulted in the class*

Comment: Ah, I see, so the `Hi::Hi() = default` means it is "not in the class". Okay just to clarify again, what makes it such that defining a ctor of a derived class will flag the static member as "used"? Is it simply because the class without defined ctor is compiled away, and the class with ctor will call the base ctor (which "uses" it)?

Comment: Right, if you define a ctor of the derived class, then it uses the ctor of the base class (and everything else it calls), and the ctor of the base class uses the static member.

Comment: Hmm, now I'm getting a bit confused. What is "used"? In my example code, I don't actually "use" any of these classes explicitly, I only specified the constructors (and did not use them). How come they are considered "used"?

Comment: Used in this context is odr-used, which has precise (and long) [definition](https://eel.is/c++draft/basic.def.odr#term.odr.use) in the standard.

Comment: The more I know C++, the more I know that I don't know C++, haha. Thanks a lot man!